# Probability that the man is the first to die

Tags: probability

> If p is the probability that a man aged x will die in a year then the
>   probability that out of n men $A_1, A_2 ,A_3 ...A_n$, each aged x,
>   $A_1$ will die in an year and be the first to die is: ?
>
> a) $1- (1- p)^{n-1}$
>
> b)$(1-p)^n$
>
> c) $\dfrac 1n [1- (1-p)^n]$
>
> d) $\dfrac 1n (1-p)^n$

**Attempt:**

Order of dying matters.

Choose $r$  out of $n-1$ and arrange them (i.e. their deaths) in $r!$ ways.

So $P(E)  = p\times{^{n-1}C_0} (1- p)^{n-1}+ p \times p\times {^{n-1}C_1} (1-p)^{n-1} + p\times p^2 \times 2!\times {^{n-1}C_2} (1- p)^{n-2}+...$

$\implies P(E) = p \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} {^{n-1}}C_r (1-p)^{n-1-r}p^r \times r!$

But this doesn't match any of the options.

Could someone please tell me where I have gone wrong?

**Edit:** My prime focus is the mistake that I have made in solving which that question doesn't cover. therefore, please don't mark it as a duplicate

Comment: My prime focus is the mistake that I have made in solving which that question doesn't cover. therefore, please don't mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Abcd: If you look my answer below, you will notice your mistake is on $\mathbb{P}[A_1\ \text{dies first} \mid N=r]$.

Comment: @Daniel Didnt understand what you mean.

Comment: @Abcd: the actual value of $\mathbb{P}[A_1\ \text{dies first} \mid N=r]$ is $\frac{1}{r+1}$, and you considered it being $r!$. The probability of $A_1$ being the first among $A_1, A_{i_1}, \ldots, A_{i_r}$ is $\frac{r!}{(r+1)!}$.

Comment: @Daniel $r!$ is for arrangement death of $A_2 , A3 ,etc$  not for $A_1$

Comment: @Abcd You do not take into account that $A_1$ dies first.

Comment: @Abcd, $r!$ is the number of orderings that begin with $A_1$ and continue with any order of $A_{i_1}, \ldots, A_{i_r}$. However, this is not the probability of the event we want. We have to divide by all the possible orderings of $A_1, A_{i_1}, \ldots, A_{i_r}$.

Comment: @Daniel Of course I did. After keeping it aside, I arranged the other r deaths.

Comment: @Daniel But in my attempt, r does not begin at $A_1$ , $r$ people are chosen from $n-1$ that is: $A_2...A_{n-1}$

Comment: @Abcd I am running out of ways of trying to explain this, but let us try one more time. With probability $p \cdot \binom{n-1}{r} p^r (1-p)^{n-1-r}$ we have *exactly* $r+1$ deaths: $A_1, B_1, \ldots, B_r$. We only need to determine the order they died now and for that we consider all orderings have the same probability. So, we want $\frac{\text{# orderings start with $A_1$}}{\text{# orderings}} = \frac{r!}{(r+1)!} = \frac{1}{r+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is almost correct. Let $N$ be the number of deaths out of $A_2, \ldots, A_n$. We know that $A_1$ must die. After that, we decompose the event with respect to $N$ (notice we are assuming all deaths are independent) and use that given $N = r$, the probability that the first to die is $A_1$ is $\frac{1}{r+1}$ (here assuming that any order of deaths is equally likely). Thus:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[\text{given event}]
  &= \mathbb{P}[A_1\ \text{dies}] \cdot \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \mathbb{P}[N=r] \cdot \mathbb{P}[A_1\ \text{dies first} \mid N=r]\\
  &= p \cdot \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{r} p^r (1-p)^{n-1-r} \cdot \frac{1}{r+1}
\end{align*}
To simplify the expression above, we notice that
$$
\binom{n-1}{r}\frac{1}{r+1} = \frac1n \binom{n}{r+1}.
$$
From the above, we can write
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[\text{given event}]
  &= \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{r+1} p^{r+1} (1-p)^{n-1-r} \\
  &= \frac1n [(p + (1-p))^n - (1-p)^n] = \frac1n [1 - (1-p)^n].
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

They probability for a person aged $x$ to not die is $1-p$. Hence, the probability that none of them is $(1-p)^n$. Therefore, the probability that at least one of them will die is $1-(1-p)^n$. SInce every one of them has the same probability to be that first person (as all are identical), it being $A_1$ has probability ${1 \over n}[1-(1-p)^n]$.

Hence, option $(c)$ is correct.

Comment: OK, but what's my mistake?

Comment: Your reasoning gives the same answer than mine. However, I got a bit confused here. We have $1 - (1-p)^n$ is the probability of someone dying (we have no control over who is dead and who is not). The question especifically states that $A_1$ must die. How is this reasoning ensuring it?

Comment: And have you accounted for the fact that A1 has to be the **first to die**

Comment: @Daniel The logic is that since all of the $n$ persons are identical and no one has any special properties, means that all have same probability to be that person.

Comment: @Abcd The first question is "is anyone dead?" That's handled inside the brackets. The next question is, "who was the first one?" I simply argue that since no one has any special properties, all must have same probability.

Comment: @SinTan1729: I see the reasoning, and yet there is something misterious about it.

Comment: What? How can persons be identical!?

Comment: @Abcd Because none of them have special features, do they? You wouldn't know if I renamed $A_1$ to $A_2$.

Comment: But you didn't tell me the mistake in my attempt.

Comment: That is explained quite well by @Daniel in the comments.